# Is there a way to query JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json, class, filesystems

I've used Google, Yahoo, AND Bing, but I can't find any good answers. I've seen jLinq, but I want to be able to query JSON in PHP in hopes of having a not an SQL database, but instead all data storage within the filesystem on my server. No, I don't care how bad it sounds.

Ideas nonetheless? I would think that there would be a PHP class on this.

-----EDIT-----

Guys, thanks for your answers so far, but I don't think that json_encode and json_decode are of much use. What I want to be able to do is encode/decode JSON, and be able to search it for specific keys with specific values. Albeit I have PROVEN to myself that I can do so, it's a lot of code for something that should be so simple. Anything else you have in mind?

Comment: i voted this as a dupe, but i was wrong and cant retract my vote.

Comment: google for stuff like "linq php" "php query" to find tons of projects.

Comment: 'sokay, rambo coder.

And thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: @RickyYoder, look at mongodb. Perfect to store json data and query it.

Comment: JSON can be easily used as serialization format of in-memory "database", but I'm not sure you are looking for that... Are you looking for CRUD acccess directly to JSON file?

Comment: I guess you could say that. I want to get specific parts of a JSON file in an easy manner.

Comment: Go for mongodb. PHP has good support for it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use JsonQ package. This package can query over JSON data like Query Builder.

https://github.com/nahid/jsonq

Answer (score 0):

You can call `json_encode` to convert your data to a string, and write this string to a file. Then when you want to use it, you read the entire file and call `json_decode` to convert it back to data. When you're done processing it, repeat the encode/write steps.

But if you have multiple processes doing this, they'll completely overwrite what each other is doing. So it's not a very good way to manage shared data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) it allows you to query json with xpath as you would xml.

Answer (score -1):

Look into [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).  This lets you take JSON as a string and parse it into an object in PHP.  You could theoretically store the strings as files, and use [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) to retrieve the string from the file.

You would have to write your own searching/indexing/updating/etc algorithms, but if you don't want to use a real database solution (since you said, *No, I don't care how bad it sounds.*), then I guess this would work.

To search for values in the object you get from `json_decode`, look into [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)